# Neural Networks for solving regression tasks by using linear activation function

Tags: neural-network, regression

By using a linear activation function in the output layer of a neural network for solving regression tasks, are we constraining the resultant model to be linear in the input features?

Comment: No. You can have a non linear activation functions in some of the hidden layers, which makes the model nonlinear even if the output activation function is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Adding activation functions to any of the layers in the model induces non linearity.

So by adding a linear activation function only at the output layer but other activation functions (sigmoid, relu etc.) to the hidden layers makes the model non-linear.